# Evaluate $\int_1^5 \sqrt{4-(x-3)^2} dx.$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate the definite integral

$$\int_1^5 \sqrt{4-(x-3)^2} dx.$$

I a initially thought I could use trig substitution but that would not work. I'm assuming u-substitution of some sort

Comment: What if you try some other substituions before the trigonometric one?

Comment: oh, such as u = x-3?

Comment: that would work. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Comment: See [Euler substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution). You can use $u(x-1)=\sqrt{-(x-1)(x-5)}$.

Comment: Geometrically, this is the area of a semi-cricle with radius $2$, which is $2\pi$. A visualization of the problem could always be helpful :-)

Answer (score 1):

Trigonometric substitution will work 
Hint :
Take $x-3=2sin\theta$

So, $dx=2cos\theta d\theta $

You would have an integrand of the form of $cos^2\theta$

Write it in the form of $cos2\theta$

Change the limits appropriately and integrate

Answer (score 0):

Try with the trigonometric sustitution $\;2\sin t=x-3,\quad -\frac{\pi}{2}\le t \le \frac{\pi}{2}\implies 1\le x \le 5 $:
\begin{align}
\int_1^5\sqrt{4-(x-3)^2}\,dx&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{4-4\sin^2 t}\cdot 2\cos t\,dt
\end{align}